# python - search and count bigrams from string (count substring occurence in string)?

Tags: python, string, text-mining, n-gram

Goal is to fetch count of bigram occurrence in string
In other words, how to get the count of a substring in a larger string?

```
# Sample data with text
hi = {1: "My name is Lance John", 
  2: "Am working at Savings Limited in Germany",
  3: "Have invested in mutual funds",
  4: "Savings Limited accepts mutual funds as investment option",
  5: "Savings Limited also accepts other investment option"}

hi = pd.DataFrame(hi.items(), columns = ['id', 'notes'])
# have two categories with pre-defined words
name = ['Lance John', 'Germany']
finance = ['Savings Limited', 'investment option', 'mutual funds']

# want count of bigrams in each category for each record
# the output should look like this

ID name finance  
1    1    0  
2    1    2
3    0    1
4    0    3
5    0    2
```

Comment: am aware of string.count(substring), but not aware of optimal method to search for multiple words for each row?

Comment: Regex would be optimal in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with regular expressions. We often assume regular expressions are "magic" since they can do everything in a single function call.

I don't know if a regexp to find different words in different groups can be that much more efficient than a more manual search - but it will certainly be more efficient than a manual search in pure Python code, as the search takes place in a highly optimized bytecode running in a tight loop.

So, if you'd only have one group, all you  need would be a regexp with your patterns separated by the "or" (`|`) regexp operator - it would match on each word. You could them use the "finditer" regexp method, along with the `collections.Counter` data structure to sum up the ocurrences of each word:

```
In [56]: test = "parrot parrot bicycle parrot inquisition bicycle parrot"

In [57]: expression = re.compile("parrot|bicycle|inquisition")

In [58]: Counter(match.group() for match in expression.finditer(test))
Out[58]: Counter({'parrot': 4, 'bicycle': 2, 'inquisition': 1})
```

Now, you extend the concept - put your correlate expressions inside regular expressions named groups (subpatterns enclosed by Parenthesis, and prefixed with `?P<groupname>` inside the parenthesis, with literal enclosing  `<  >` for the groupname). Each group body is the sequence of your words above, and each group name your collection name - so:

```
 expression = r'(?P<finance>Savings\ Limited|investment\ option|mutual\ funds)|(?P<name>Lance\ John|Germany)')
```

Would yield the matches in groups named `finance` and `name` accordingly for the example you gave.  To sun that up with the counter, we have to use the `groupdict` method of the expression match object, and take the keys of the resulting dict -

```
In[65]: Counter(m.groupdict().keys()[0] for m in expression.finditer(hi[1]))
Out[65]: Counter({'finance': 1})
```

Now just get a way to build your expression programatically instead of having to hardcode it - it can be done with two nested "join" operators  - the outer one to concatenate the groups, and the inner one to concatenate the terms in each group.

It will be more elegant if you put your terms in a dictionary, instead of naming each as an isolated variable - so you'd have:

```
 domains = {'finance': [...], 'names': [...]}
```

And the regexp above can be built by:

```
groups = []
for groupname in domains.keys():
    term_group = "|".join(re.escape(term) for term in terms)
    groups.append(r"(?P<{}>{})".format(groupname, term_group)  ) 
expression = re.compile("|".join(groups))
```

And then, just sun up your data:

```
data = []
for key, textline in hi.items():
    data.append((key, Counter(m.groupdict().keys()[0] for m in expression.finditer(textline)) ))
```

(and on a side note, perceive how terribly unreadable would be to try to build the regexp using nested generator expressions):

```
 expression = re.compile("|".join("(?P<{0}>{1})".format(
      groupname,
      "|".join(
          "{}".format(
                  re.escape(term)) for term in domains[groupname]
           )
       ) for group in domains.keys() )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hi = {1: "My name is Lance John. Lance John is senior marketing analyst", 
      2: "Am working at Savings Limited in Germany",
      3: "Have invested in mutual funds",
      4: "Savings Limited accepts mutual funds as investment option",
      5: "Savings Limited also accepts other investment option"}

hi = pd.DataFrame(hi.items(), columns = ['id', 'notes'])
name = ['Lance John', 'Germany', 'senior', 'working']
finance = ['Savings Limited', 'investment option', 'mutual funds']

def f(cell_value):
    return [((v[1])) for v in ((s, cell_value.count(s)) for s in search) if v]

search = name
df=hi['notes'].apply(f)


search = finance
df1=hi['notes'].apply(f)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': df.apply(np.count_nonzero), 'finance': df1.apply(np.count_nonzero), 'text': hi['notes']})
```

was able to solve it using this link [Counting appearances of multiple substrings in a cell pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700814/counting-appearances-of-multiple-substrings-in-a-cell-pandas)
just modified code to count unique appearances using count_nonzero instead of direct sum